# Cordova - Get the current wallpaper

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-plugin-file

1) How can I get the current wallpaper with Cordova?
Is there any easiest way?
2) how can I get the last captured image of DCIM folder with Cordova ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of android systems is the wallpaper located in here:

`/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper`

For the image you can use a mix of a plugin and the function:

```
camera.getPicture
```

Plugin:
https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library

this give you the necessary ID of a picture. Within is a date when the picture was made. So with a bit of customizing you can get what you want with that.

Have a nice day